# git best approch to store an optional feature

Tags: git

For example, I have a feature that I want to delete in my master branch, but I want to keep this part of the code in case I need it in the future. What should I do?

What I'm trying to do:
-save the current code as a new branch A;
-switch to master branch, delete code;
-continue work on the master branch.

Question: Once master branch merges other commits, if I want to restore the feature code in the branch A, should I just merge branch A? Does it bring back the old unmodified codes which might be modified in new commits?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just delete the feature you do not need and make a commit out of the deletion.

If you later decide that you need it, you can retrieve it by reverting the deletion commit with:

```
git revert <commit>
```

E.g.

commit which removes the feature:

```
c087269 (HEAD -> master) Delete feature X
```

what to run when you need the feature back:

```
git revert c087269
```